# How to add Today/Tomorrow to the datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap datepicker in my application. Is there any way to add `Today` `Tomorrow` buttons to the datepicker.

I have not found anything here https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: The trick is to use their **Custom date format** and `.pipe()` in order to say 'if today, then change format to string "Today" '. It isn't directly built in, but can be implemented with a little elbow grease using the above strategy.

Comment: You mean we will place the buttons inside or outside?